# Programming an Op Amp in C

Tags: c

I'm having a quick attempt at modelling a simple op amp distortion circuit in C, quite like: [Schematic](http://www.gmarts.org/pix/schem/a_amp-odrv.gif). At the moment though, I'm merely trying to simulate a standard non inverting amplifier.

I've written what I think should work as code though I'm probably drastically wrong somewhere!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float Diode(float IP){
    if(IP<0.7) return 0;
    if(IP>0.7) return IP-0.7;
}

float OpAmp(float VI, float VN){
    const float AOL = 100000;
    const float VNS = -15, VPS = 15;
    float OP = 0;

    OP = AOL*(VN - VI);
    if(OP>VPS) OP = VPS;
    if(OP<VNS) OP = VNS;

    return OP;
}

int main()
{
    float C, OP = 0, IVI = 0;
    const float R1 = 100, R2 = 100;

    FILE *f, *f2;

    f = fopen("wf.txt", "w");
    f2 = fopen("ws.txt", "w");

    for(C = 0; C<8*M_PI; C+=0.1){
         //Inverting input variable   
        IVI = OP*R2/(R1+R2);
        printf("%f\n", IVI);

        OP = OpAmp(IVI, sinf(C));

        fprintf(f, "%.2f\n", OP);
        fprintf(f2, "%.2f\n", sinf(C));
    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(f2);

    return 0;
}
```

The diode function isnt in use yet, its just there if I ever manage to get this to work! I'm writing to files so I can plot the outputs in matlab though at the moment, as the output, i'm just getting mad oscillation! The "power supply" is limited to +/-15v, any help is appreciated!

I'm wondering why the output isn't a scaled version of the input with respect to the ratio of R1 and R2?

Comment: Is there a ***question*** in here?

Comment: Given that the standard approximation for pencil-and-paper design with op amps is to treat them as infinite gain elements constrained by their feedback loop, this may be an interesting challenge.

Comment: My apologies @abelenky, I'm wondering why the output isn't a scaled version of the input with respect to the ratio of R1 and R2 and how I can possibly incorporate it!

Comment: @Pyrohaz To get better answers,  update your post with your above comment and ask a question - the kind with a '?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have modeled the op amp gives it an infinite slew rate with very slow feedback. The output can swing from -VS to +VS instantly, in zero time, but it takes non-zero time for the inputs to see the effect of that change. A real amplifier just doesn't work this way and I'm not sure that it can be properly modeled in the manner that you are attempting to do it. You could try slowing down the output slew rate by limiting the change in the output to perhaps 1% of the supply voltage, then using a very slowly changing input with a small amplitude. Once you get something reasonable you can twiddle the slew limiting paramater.

Best idea: use SPICE instead.

Answer (score 0):

The OpAmp function seems suspicious. The multiplication with AOL makes OP become very, very high or very, very low (as in around +700000 or -700000), and then you clamp it to +-15. Are you sure you have the correct unit for AOL?

Comment: AOL was just meant to be the open loop gain, could that be where my implementation is wrong?